# Display three of the most viewed articles

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsf

I have a html `ul` list with 9 elements. Each of these have a picture and a link to a specific html page when pressing Continue reading.

I want to create a section on the page called Top Articles where I want to display three of the most viewed articles from the list of nine based on mouse clicks (when I press continue reading). If the order of the most viewed articles changes, I want on page reload my Top Article section changing too.

I am using Apache Tomcat server and the project uses JSF framework. Note that I don't have a database connection, I keep my data(text) in XML files, then convert XML to XSL and finally with a Java parser I converst XSL files in html (the links Continue reading take me to these html files) .

Would you help me please with an idea how to solve this, I need to use Java or JavaScript. I am thinking about a counter that memorize mouse clicks in a cookie and the load the the 3 most viewed articles in the Top Articles section based on the information stored in cookie but I don't know how to do that.

[Here is a printscreen with ul list of 9 articles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oWw9.png)

Comment: why dont you create a tag for viewCount under article in your XML, and increase the count on every click, then navigate/display the article?

Comment: Why don't you try the LRU (Least Recently Used) algorithm, to get the 3 most viewed articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to maintain & store the view counts in XML file can be - create a "viewCount" tag in that XML file. After user view a particular Article increment the viewCount for that article.

For the increment logic you can create a web service which can be pinged using AJAX feature in java script which does not interrupt the user & hit the service in background & make a increment for viewCount on that article.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a view count tag to each of the article tag in your xml. Increment it every view and use the tag value while displaying.

You can also have a websocket to get the latest counter value from server to the clients. check out comet implementations